# How to group and transpose my dataframe in a specific way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
id    type   value
a      K1     10
b      K1     14
c      K1     8
a      M4     17
b      M4     20
d      M4     34
e      M4     90
```

I want to group by id and then transpose in such way to get this:

```
id    K1   M4
a     10   17
b     14   20
c     8    NA
d     NA   34
e     NA   90
```

How to do that? Which functions may I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot table does exactly what you want.

```
df.pivot(index='id', columns='type', values='value')
```